Laser Scan rotates with robot
Required Info:
Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
ROS2 Version: ROS2 Humble
The LaserScan rotating with robot when I use teleop_twist_keyboard to manually rotate the robot. I am using the rplidar_ros package to run the lidar I am unable to perform navigation and mapping I tried mapping
As LaserScan rotates I am unable to perform navigation? How To keep LaserScan fixed while robot is rotating?
Video
Map when lidar frame is rotating with robot:

Tf tree:


@jsotola As LaserScan rotates I am unable to perform navigation? How To keep LaserScan fixed while robot is rotating?

Have you checked if the Odom frame is rotating, which can cause the laser scan to rotate?

thank you for clarifying your post ... please do not put question marks at end of statements ... the first sentence is not a question, it does not ask anything

you can delete the comments ... they are not part of the question, and are just clutter when all information is contained within the question
